# Laravel y PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, phpunit, tdd

Tengo como entorno de desarrollo Windows 8 y Laragon. He creado un nuevo proyecto para empezar a aprender sobre el TDD. Cuando intento ejecutar el comando `phpunit` desde la consola, en la raíz del proyecto, tal como indica la documentación, me responde `bash: phpunit: command not found`.

Los tests que vienen por defecto se ejecutan si tecleo `vendor/bin/phpunit`.

Esto es normal? Por qué no me funciona el comando tal como aparece en la documentación? Puede ser un error en la creación del proyecto?

Comment: Es normal si no tienes instalado phpunit globalmente. Si no quieres instalarlo globalmente puedes usar el de tu proyecto sin problema.

Comment: Y como lo instalaría globalmente? Con Composer? Y si lo instalo globalmente, el phpunit que instale va a ser compatible con Laravel? Gracias por las aclaraciones.

Comment: Sí, con composer es la más fácil `composer global require phpunit/phpunit ^latest` para la última versión (requiere PHP 7.2), o puedes especificarle la versión que uses `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=5.4.*"`. Mira la versión del que se instaló en tu proyecto en el archivo `composer.json`una línea como ésta `"phpunit/phpunit": "^8"`, donde 8 es la versión, usa la misma y va a ser compatible con tu proyecto Laravel, lo único que cambia es que va a estar disponible globalmente. https://forum.laragon.org/topic/145/phpunit-in-laragon